# How to I return a json object along with totals in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database of exercises in a workout tracker, and when I do a find(), the result is this:

```
[
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b2d",
"day": "2020-04-10T14:07:55.905Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Bicep Curl",
"duration": 20,
"weight": 100,
"reps": 10,
"sets": 4
}
]
},
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b2e",
"day": "2020-04-11T14:07:55.916Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Lateral Pull",
"duration": 20,
"weight": 300,
"reps": 10,
"sets": 4
}
]
},
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b2f",
"day": "2020-04-12T14:07:55.916Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Push Press",
"duration": 25,
"weight": 185,
"reps": 8,
"sets": 4
}
]
},
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b30",
"day": "2020-04-13T14:07:55.916Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "cardio",
"name": "Running",
"duration": 25,
"distance": 4
}
]
},
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b31",
"day": "2020-04-14T14:07:55.916Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Bench Press",
"duration": 20,
"weight": 285,
"reps": 10,
"sets": 4
}
]
},
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b32",
"day": "2020-04-15T14:07:55.916Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Bench Press",
"duration": 20,
"weight": 300,
"reps": 10,
"sets": 4
}
]
},
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b33",
"day": "2020-04-16T14:07:55.916Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Quad Press",
"duration": 30,
"weight": 300,
"reps": 10,
"sets": 4
}
]
},
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b34",
"day": "2020-04-17T14:07:55.916Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Bench Press",
"duration": 20,
"weight": 300,
"reps": 10,
"sets": 4
}
]
},
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b35",
"day": "2020-04-18T14:07:55.916Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Military Press",
"duration": 20,
"weight": 300,
"reps": 10,
"sets": 4
}
]
},
{
"_id": "5e9dacbb6512969974bd5b36",
"day": "2020-04-19T14:07:55.916Z",
"exercises": [
{
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Bench",
"duration": 30,
"distance": 2
}
]
}
]
```

Then I need to get total sums of statistics from each exercise, so I used mongoose aggregate to give me this data:

```
[
{
"_id": null,
"totalDuration": 230,
"totalWeight": 2070,
"totalSets": 32,
"totalReps": 78,
"totalDistance": 6
}
]
```

I want to combine these two results in one GET request, ideally doing something similar to a push where I just push the totals at the end of the first JSON object. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    function mergeResults(resultFromFindQuery, totalSums){
    var allData = {};
    allData['mongoFindresult'] = resultFromFindQuery;
    allData['totalSums'] = totalSums;
    return allData;
    }
```

Then use the returned value to what you need to do. Now you have both of them in the same variable.